# Does drinking recommended amounts of alcohol do more harm to children aged 13 to 18 than it does to adults?

Tags: medical-science, alcohol

The [National Institute for Alcohol Abuse and Alcoholism](http://pubs.niaaa.nih.gov/publications/AA67/AA67.htm) strongly implies that consuming *any* alcohol at all while under the age of 18 is excessively detrimental to one's health.

While never stated outright, this implication is visible in places such as this:

> Whatever it is that leads adolescents to begin drinking, once they start they face a number of potential health risks.

For adults, most studies indicate that a regular diet of one or two drinks a day is healthy--and in fact may have health benefits.

Would drinking one or two drinks a day (or less) do more physiological harm to a 13 to 18 year old than an adult?

Comment: Also it's worth noting, that in many European countries legal age is 16 for non-distilled alcohol such as beer or wine.

Comment: There might be two factors at play: short and long term effects. Maybe there is more immediate harm (and maybe not) but maybe introducing the young to safe use of alcohol makes them less likely to abuse it later.

Comment: @vartec: Several European countries do not have a legal drinking age at all. Even if there is a minimum age required to purchase alcohol, it is not necessarily forbidden for minors to drink alcohol or for legal buyers to hand alcohol over to minors (with minors used in the meaning of persons below legal purchase age).

Comment: @Tor-EinarJarnbjo: only in the sense that minors are not punished by law if caught drinking, but selling or providing alcohol do minors is still illegal.

Comment: @vartec: If Wikipedia's list of legal drinking age is correct, you are wrong. There are several countries in Europe, where it is neither illegal for minors to drink alcohol, nor for adults to provide alcohol for children: Austria, Bulgaria, Denmark, Germany, Ireland, Montenegro, Romania, Russia, Sweden and United Kingdom. The list may of course be inaccurate, but probably not for all these countries. Interesting enough, in the UK it is forbidden to give alcohol to children under the age of 5.

Comment: Here's a claim from the [Japanese underage drinking campaign site](http://www.stop-underagedrinking.com/english/project.html): `It has a significant impact on the brain cells of developing bodies and places young people at high risk for stunted growth and gonadal disorders (irregular menstruation, impotence, etc.). It also places you at higher risk of damage to organs such as the liver and pancreas.`

Comment: @KenY-N There's an obvious bias there and no studies cited.

Comment: Here's a paper on teenage drinking: http://www.sciencedirect.com/science/article/pii/S0091743504002658 I'm skeptical of their methods, as they seem to focus on *abuse* by teenagers, but there is one interesting claim: "Individuals who first use alcohol before age 14 years are at increased risk of developing alcohol use disorders."

Comment: This paper seems like it might have a solid methodology: http://onlinelibrary.wiley.com/doi/10.1046/j.1360-0443.2001.9610148512.x/abstract;jsessionid=ACEF32CFBDB665040E6507BC95E2A326.f03t04?deniedAccessCustomisedMessage=&userIsAuthenticated=false Does anyone have access to it? I might have to purchase it later.

Comment: @Tor-EinarJarnbjo, in Sweden, at least, giving alcohol to someone underage could get you up to four years in prison ([source](http://polisen.se/Lagar-och-regler/Om-olika-brott/Alkohol--och-narkotikabrott/Fakta-om-langning-av-alkohol/)), so your sources are obviously flawed.

Comment: @Zano: No, you are linking to an incomplete summary of the Swedish alcohol code. The relevant statement is found in "Alkohollagen (2010:1622), 3. kap, § 9" and states under which conditions it is allowed to offer alcohol beverages to persons below the (otherwise) legal drinking age.

Comment: As far as I can tell, the given claim doesn't really match what's being asked. Like is said, it's never stated outright. Do young drinkers face "potential health risks"? **Yes**, along with other drinkers, depending on the amount consumed. There's a reason they don't use stronger, more specific language here. There's no qualifier about the amount consumed, etc. It's just a broad, over-generic statement about alcohol.

Comment: @Geobits You are correct that the publication I quoted intentionally avoided making a strong claim, but there are many locales where this is carried to the degree I pointed out in my question. The popularity of my question, I think, is circumstantial evidence that this is a notable claim, if not directly claimed by the NIAAA.

Comment: I'd still rather see a direct claim stating that adolescents suffer more physiological harm than adults from the same consumption levels (if that's the actual question). I'm sure that *somebody* has made this claim somewhere. I don't doubt that it's notable, just that the claim you've presented/linked to isn't it.

Comment: Does this take into account body weight? A child will be affected twice as badly from the same amount of alcohol as an adult who weighs twice as much, just because of the body weight. So "two drinks" will clearly affect the average 13 year old worse than the average adult. Same as a tiny and very slim adult woman will be affected worse by "two drinks" than a much heavier person.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

**Drinking one or two drinks shows higher estimated BACs (which might relate to more harm due to impairment in reasoning, depth perception, peripheral vision and glare recovery) in a 13 to 18 year old than an adult with relation to body weight.** Research shows that at one standard drink, peak BACs ranges from 62.0 mg/dL for 9-year-old boys to 27.4 mg/dL for 17-year-old boys, and from 61.9 mg/dL for 9-year-old girls to 38.2 mg/dL for 17-year-old girls. At two drinks, the estimated peak BAC for girls aged 9-13 exceeded 80 mg/dL (81.8 to 123.9 mg/dL), while only those for boys aged 9-12 reached this level (84.6 to 124.0 mg/dL).

**Children and adolescents exhibited higher estimated BACs than adults at each level of alcohol intake since "Both children and early adolescents weigh substantially less than adults and would likely achieve considerably higher BAC levels after five drinks within a 2-hour period or would reach a BAC ≥ 80 mg/dL after significantly fewer drinks"** per study by Donovan JE in [2009](http://www.ncbi.nlm.nih.gov/pmc/articles/PMC2690712/).  A BAC level of 20 mg/dl or higher is considered indicative of alcohol use and BAC levels greater than 80 mg/dL (>17.4 mmol/L) is considered positive for driving under the influence in most states in USA. Per the study, at three drinks, the estimated peak BAC for all children aged 9-17 were 2.3 times greater than the NIAAA binge drinking level for the youngest children (i.e., 186.0 and 185.8 mg/dL for 9-year-old boys and girls, respectively)

> At one standard drink, boys and girls could theoretically achieve peak BACs ranging from 62.0 mg/dL for 9-year-old boys to 27.4 mg/dL for 17-year-old boys, and from 61.9 mg/dL for 9-year-old girls to 38.2 mg/dL for 17-year-old girls. At two drinks, the estimated peak BAC for girls aged 9-13 exceeded 80 mg/dL (81.8 to 123.9 mg/dL), while only those for boys aged 9-12 reached this level (84.6 to 124.0 mg/dL). At three drinks, the estimated peak BAC for all children aged 9-17 exceeded the 80 mg/dL NIAAA criterion, and were 2.3 times this level for the youngest children (i.e., 186.0 and 185.8 mg/dL for 9-year-old boys and girls, respectively). At five standard drinks, estimated peak BACs ranged from 137.1 to 309.9 mg/dL for boys and from 191.1 to 309.7 mg/dL for girls, levels that can result in coma and respiratory problems in children and early adolescents.
>
> The more standard drinks consumed at each age, the higher the estimated BAC. Also, the younger the child, the higher the estimated post-peak BAC at each intake level. For ages 9-13, the mean estimated BACs for boys and girls were comparable at each level: mean BACs for girls fell within the 95% CI for boys the same age. For ages 14 through 17, girls had higher estimated BACs than boys at each intake level, with no overlap in their 95% CIs.
>
> **RESULTS:** The estimated BAC for children after consuming just three standard drinks within a 2-hour period was between 80 and 139 mg/dL for boys aged 9-13 and for girls aged 9-17, indicating substantial potential alcohol impairment. At five drinks within 2 hours, the level used to define binge drinking among college students, children aged 9-13 were estimated to have BACs two to three times the adult legal limit for intoxication of 80 mg/dL.
>
> **CONCLUSIONS:** Binge drinking assessment in children and adolescents requires substantially lower cut-points than those used for college students. Binge drinking should be defined as 3 or more drinks for 9-13 year olds, as 4 or more drinks for boys and 3 or more drinks for girls aged 14 or 15, and as 5 or more drinks for boys and 3 or more drinks for girls aged 16 or 17.

"The National Institute on Alcohol Abuse and Alcoholism (NIAAA) redefined binge drinking as a drinking pattern that brings a person’s blood alcohol concentration (BAC) to 80 mg/dL or above, a level accompanied by significant physical and mental impairment. For the typical adult, this pattern corresponds to five drinks by a man or four drinks by a woman within a 2-hour period." and definition of standard drink can be found [here](http://www.camy.org/factsheets/sheets/alcohol_advertising_promotion/Call_To_Action.pdf).

First use of alcohol at ages 11-14 greatly heightens the risk of progression to the development of alcohol disorders per study by DeWit DJ et.al. in [2000](https://www.ncbi.nlm.nih.gov/pubmed/10784467). "Body of evidence, however, does suggest that early exposure to alcohol may set adolescents up for problem drinking later on, and that delaying the first drink for as long as possible may help to foster more responsible alcohol [habits](http://healthland.time.com/2013/05/24/if-drinking-starts-at-puberty-its-more-likely-to-lead-to-alcohol-problems/)."

The health risks of youth drinking per [NIAAA](http://pubs.niaaa.nih.gov/publications/AA67/AA67.htm) are

1. **Brain Effects by animal studies** — "It’s simply not known how alcohol will affect the long-term memory and learning skills of people who began drinking heavily as adolescents. Scientists currently are examining just how alcohol affects the developing brain, and research has shown that animals fed alcohol during this critical developmental stage continue to show long-lasting impairment from alcohol as they age". Alcohol use during DSM-IV alcohol dependent adolescence is associated with prefrontal volume abnormalities, including white matter [differences](http://www.ncbi.nlm.nih.gov/pmc/articles/PMC2825148/). Additional research is necessary to know the exact effects of alcohol on the adolescent hippocampus and other brain structures and to better understand the long-term implications of adolescent alcohol [exposure](http://pubs.niaaa.nih.gov/publications/arh284/213-221.htm).
2. **Liver Effects** — "Elevated liver enzymes, indicating some degree of liver damage, have been found in some adolescents who drink alcohol. Young drinkers who are overweight or obese showed elevated liver enzymes even with only moderate levels of [drinking](http://www.ncbi.nlm.nih.gov/pubmed/11584156)".
3. **Growth and Endocrine Effects by animal studies**— "In both males and females, puberty is a period associated with marked hormonal changes, including increases in the sex hormones, estrogen and testosterone. These hormones, in turn, increase production of other hormones and growth factors which are vital for normal organ development. Drinking alcohol during this period of rapid growth and development (i.e., prior to or during puberty) may upset the critical hormonal balance necessary for normal development of organs, muscles, and bones. Studies in animals also show that consuming alcohol during puberty adversely affects the maturation of the reproductive system".

Comment: Most of your evidence is about association, not direct harm. I have no trouble believing that early drinking is associated  with future alcohol abuse. I have trouble believing that possible future alcohol abuse is direct harm caused by early drinking.

Comment: @Skliwz- Point taken. The evidence for physiological harm to a 13 to 18 year old's 1. Brain Effects-Animals fed with alcohol research. 2. Liver Effects—Elevated liver enzymes, indicating some degree of liver damage, have been found in some adolescents who drink alcohol. Young drinkers who are overweight or obese showed elevated liver enzymes even with only moderate levels of drinking. 3. Growth and Endocrine Effects-"Studies in animals also show that consuming alcohol during puberty adversely affects the maturation of the reproductive system" From Underage Drinking-NIAAA 2006 document.

Comment: @pericles316 For the direct effects you do not qualify what levels of consumption produce the effects.

Comment: @called2voyage-references for levels of consumption of alcohol in adolescents for binge drinking added.